# How to use a seal service kit (SPSK0319.1J) for a Mira Meynell V8/3 shower mixing valve

Tags: shower, seal, service

I have a Mira Meynell V8/3 shower mixing valve. It works great for years. Now, the knob has started to become stiff, especially it needs to be turned quite hard to the fully clockwise position which turns off the cold water supplier entirely.

I have ordered a Meynell V8/3 seal pack (SPSK0319.1J). I wonder if there is any instruction on how to install it.

https://www.showerspares.com/search/meynell_v8_3_seal_pack_spsk0319.1j/

[image: Mira Meynell V8/3 seal pack (SPSK0319.1J)]

*Update on 15 March*: The following exploded view is the best I could find. However, it is for Mira Safemix V8/3 but not Mira Meynell V8/3. Parts marked with "A" could be the spares in the seal service kit. If yes, there are a lots of things need to be taken apart. I don't feel entirely confident about the prospect of losing [both hot and cold] water supply, if I leave the job half-done. I really wish to have some reassurance with the knowledge of certain proper instructions.

https://www.showerspares.com/meynell_shower_spares/meynell_all/meynell_safemix_v8_3_pesm0563p/

[image: Mira Safemix V8/3 exploded view]

*References*

[1] Installation manual, exploded drawing and a list of spare parts, pp.22-23
https://www.radacontrols.com/media/60527/1063915-w2-e-rada-meynell-v83.pdf

[2] Seal Service Kit (SPSK0319.1J) https://www.cityplumbing.co.uk/Mira-Meynell-%27S%27afemix-V8-3-%27S%27eal-Pack-%27S%27PSK0319-1J/p/622433

Comment: With packs like these it is always worth searching on Youtube - installation videos exist for almost anything

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I tried and failed to locate anything specially for V8/3 Seal Service Kit. Blame my searching (Google and YouTube) skill, or the lack of it.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the manufacturer to see if they have printed or video instructions?

Comment: That's a great suggestion. The follow is their response. I presume I'll just need to proceed with care. 

"we don't have anything other than the exploded diagram, please note this is also known as the Meynell Safemix, or just the meynell V8/3, so any diagrams with those names will help. 

we cam attend to fir the parts it will cost £135.00 plus parts plus VAT to send a trained technician to resolve the issues."